# Creating DataTable from Text File and splitting

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable, report

This is going to be my text file (30 lines)

```
OrderNo:37374
OrderQuantity:250
BarcodeQR:584,25478Klkd28
NormalBarcode:1565484864
.......
.......
.......
```

This is the code :

```
public DataTable DTforReport()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataColumn col = new DataColumn("test");
    col.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
    dt.Columns.Add(col);

    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\\abc\\Desktop\\abc.txt");
    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        var segments = line.Split(';');
        foreach (var seg in segments)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = seg;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
    }
    return dt;
}
```

I want my output like this

```
 OrderNo  OrderQuantity   BarcodeQR
  37374       250       584,25478Klkd28
```

How can I change my code to achieve this?

Comment: Off-Topic: The default value for type of the column is string. But if for any reason you want to specify the type, instead of uding `System.Type.GetType("System.String")` use `typeof(string)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have generated only one column. Change your code like below to see your desired result:

```
public DataTable DTforReport()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\\abc\\Desktop\\abc.txt");
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        DataColumn col = new DataColumn(lines[i].Split(':')[0]);
        col.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
        dt.Columns.Add(col);
        var segment = lines[i].Split(':')[1];               
        dr[i] = segment;                
    }

    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    return dt;
}
```

Comment: you are the hero gotham needs :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to modify your method like the following:

```
public DataTable DTforReport()
{
    DataTable testTable = new DataTable("Test");
    testTable.Columns.Add("OrderNo");
    testTable.Columns.Add("OrderQuantity");
    testTable.Columns.Add("BarcodeQR");
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\\abc\\Desktop\\abc.txt");
    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        DataRow dRow = testTable.NewRow();
        var segments = line.Split(';');
        for (int i = 0; i < segments.Length; i++)
        {
            var colValues = segments[i].Split(':');
            dRow[i] = colValues[1];
        }
        testTable.Rows.Add(dRow);
    }
    return testTable;
}
```

Few suggestions for improvement:

- I have given static column names, if you want to add more or they may change in future means you can create dynamic columns in the datatable.
- If you have doubts in the input values, make use of proper validation
- Validations in the sense, make sure about the splitted values before accessing them through index otherwise they may ends up with IndexOutOfRangeException

Comment: yea, 
i have to create dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\\abc\\Desktop\\abc.txt");
var firstLine = lines.First();
var columns = firstLine.Split(';');

for (var icount = 0; icount < columns.Count(); icount++)
{
    var colName = columns[icount].Contains(":") ? columns[icount].Split(':')[0] : "Column" + icount;
    var dataCol = new DataColumn(colName);
    dataCol.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
    dt.Columns.Add(dataCol);
}

foreach (var line in lines)
{
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    var segments = line.Split(';');
    for (var icount = 0; icount < segments.Count(); icount++)
    {
        var colVal = segments[icount].Contains(":") ? segments[icount].Split(':')[1] : "";
        dr[icount] = colVal;
    }
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

*Number of column must be same in each row.